# Is the boundary of a 0-simplex empty?

Tags: algebraic-topology

This is mostly a question about conventions and is motivated by me trying to understand the definition of Delta-complex structure given in Hatcher.

It is right to say that the boundary of 0-simplex is empty, or equivalently that a 0-simplex is equal to its interior? I believe it should be so...

Comment: Yes, it is empty.

Comment: The book says so and explains the motivation on page 110. This fits naturally with reduced homology.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, but I was checking the Delta-complex structure on the torus on page 102 :)